# My container's color property doesnt work and it doesnt give any error Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a profile page layout as its seperated by 2 and 1 positioned for avatar picture. my down container color, ı cant set it seems not working ıdk why. here is my code below:

```
body: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
          new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                height: topWidgetHeight,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: new DecorationImage(image: new AssetImage("assets/9.jpg"),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover)
                ),
              ),
              new Container(
                color: Colors.red,
              )
            ],
          ),
          new Positioned(

            child: new Container(
              height: 150,
              width: 150,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: new DecorationImage(image: new AssetImage("assets/0.jpg"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(75.0)),
                         boxShadow: [
                           BoxShadow(blurRadius: 7.0, color: Colors.black)
                         ],

              ),
            ),
            left: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2) - avatarRadius,
            top: topWidgetHeight - avatarRadius,
          )
        ],

    )
```

[image: screenchot]

Comment: the red container?

Comment: Try to give it a height and a width!!

Comment: @AbdelbakiBoukerche ahhh my bad, yea I forgot to give an height.. now ı see my container thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the container is not appearing because you have not given any height and to container

please give it height and width and then try